# Javascript - Removing leading zeros from a string of negative number

Tags: javascript

I have this string "00-12.50" and I would like to remove the leading zeros with and replace with a blank space. How do I do that?

My Regex example is not working: `strDedAmount.replace(/^[0]*/, ' ')`

This example returns " 0-12.50"
Thanks

Comment: That approach works

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error, it seems to work as is.  Are you sure that `strDedAmount` is exactly equal to "00-12.50" when `.replace` is called?

Comment: Probably you used this regex `/^[0]/` in your test.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose using the "with callback" version of string.replace(regex, callback) will serve you well

```js
const str = '00-12.50'
const fixed = str.replace(/^0+/, match => ' '.repeat(match.length))
console.log(fixed)
```

Comment: The approach that the OP is using works perfectly, I think this is unnecessary.

Comment: @Ele I don't know about "perfectly". First if his string isn't prefixed by a 0 he'll be adding a blank space anyway. Second he'll be substituting all prepending 0s by a single blank space, seems to me that he want one whitespace for each 0.

Comment: **From OP:** *I would like to remove the leading zeros with and replace with a blank space*